# QuantLib - can't reprice cash

Tags: python, quantlib

I've been struggling with QuantLib curves for a few days now, and can't reprice even simple cash:

```
import QuantLib as ql

def create_helper(rate, tenor):
    return ql.DepositRateHelper(rate, tenor, 0, ql.Australia(), ql.ModifiedFollowing, True, ql.Actual365Fixed())

cash = [(0.03015,ql.Period("1M")),(0.032647,ql.Period("3M")),(0.03765,ql.Period("6M"))]

helpers = [create_helper(rate, tenor) for rate,tenor in cash]

spot = ql.Date(30, 12, 2022)

curve = ql.PiecewiseLinearZero(spot, helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())

for rate, tenor in cash:
    instrument_date = ql.Australia().advance(spot, tenor)
    r = curve.forwardRate(spot, instrument_date, ql.Actual365Fixed(), ql.Simple, ql.Once).rate()*100
    p_rate = rate*100
    diff = abs(r-p_rate)*100
    if diff * 100 > 0.01:
        print(f"On {instrument_date} curve rate is {r}% quote is {p_rate}% diff = {diff} bps")
```

Outputs:

```
On March 30th, 2023 curve rate is 3.0223525579839206% quote is 3.2647000000000004% diff = 24.23474420160798 bps
On June 30th, 2023 curve rate is 3.2790040457701273% quote is 3.765% diff = 48.599595422987285 bps
```

The deposit rates are simple rates. It cannot be that QL would assume they are continuously compounded, since the rate I get from the curve is less than what I put in (and I'm explicitly asking for a Simple rate), and a simple rate on a given period must be more than equivalent continuously compounded rate on the same period (assuming positive rates of course).

Am entirely lost now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd try setting the evaluation date.

Comment: doh! I was pretty tired, but still